# Gatsby - make fluid Images width ImageSharp from reference field in csv-file

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I create pages from a csv-file. This file contains a field "image" with the file name of an image in `/src/images/products/` and a "category" field.

I want to create a category page with all the images of this category on it. In gatsby-node.js is the following to get the distinct categories to create a page for each category:

```
// Create Categrorie pages from CSV
    const resultCategories = await graphql (`
        query {
            allCsvFile {
                distinct(field: category)
            }
        }
    `)
    resultCategories.data.allCsvFile.distinct.forEach( category => {
        createPage({
            // Path for this page — required    
            path: category.toLowerCase(),
            component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/catalog-categoriepage.js`),
            context: {
                Category: category
            }
        })
    })
```

In /src/templates/catalog-categoriepage.js I query graphql for the other fields to make the list of items:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($Category: String!) {
    product: allCsvFile(filter: {category: {eq: $Category}}) {
      nodes {
        field1
        field2
        image
      }
    }
  }
`
```

How can I use the file name in "image" to create fluid Images for this page?
I already have the images in "allFile", but how to reference the path by the "image" field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The csv-File has to contain the relative path to the image in the filesystem, then the images are recognized and get the childImageSharp (if gatsby-transformer-shap and gatsby-plugin-sharp are installed).

Alternativley you can use onCreateNode to manipulate the node on build. See:
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/17783#issuecomment-533837059

Comment: How can I get multiple images referenced for the same line?